# Tensorflow - Numpy arrays and Shape error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a Tensorflow simple AI and I don't understand where my problem is when I compare it to various articles I read about this topic.

I have two numpy arrays made for training of sizes (N,1) (what should be predicted) and (N,3) (what are the inputs that should be predicted), and I want my algorithm to predict with Input[0,i] Input[1,i] Input[2,i] the value of ToPredict[i] (the i-th sample).
I thought I had to use  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices and then

```html
modele = tf.keras.Sequential([ tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'), tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) ]) 
modele.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
modele.fit(A, epochs=10)
```

from an example I got online. (here A represents the  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Inputs_Learning,ToPredict_Learning))

When I do that, I get the following error:

> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [3,10] and labels shape [1]
> [[node loss_9/output_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at :11) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_2640]

So I know that there is a shape error, but I don't know how to tell the algorithm what I want as shapes.

Could anyone help me? Also yes I have seen related stackoverflow posts but they don't seem to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add batch dimension to your data:

```
A = A.batch(10)
```

Comment: I changed the number in Dense. However when I transpose my data, Input becomes (3,N) and ToPredict (1,N) numpy arrays. Then, when I do tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( it returns the following error: ValueError: Dimensions 3 and 1 are not compatible @Andrey

Comment: transpose labels as well

Comment: The previous code was  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(A,B) and I changed it to  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(A.T,B.T). So I assume what you call "Labels" is B (the value to predict), which I did transpose in my previous comment

Comment: input to the network should be (N, 3), labels (what is predicted) should be (N, 1)

Comment: Ok so I still get the error mentionned in the question. The confusion arises from the fact that I said (1,N) instead of (N,1) multiple times including in the question. Sorry. Now I have two Dataset(A,B) with A and B of shapes (N,3) and (N,1) as you said and it gives the error in the question in the "fit" line.

Comment: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [3,1] and labels shape [1]
  [[node loss/output_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at <ipython-input-8-fae5fc24baa2>:11) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_623]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225281/discussion-between-packsciences-and-andrey).